# Yii::$app->user->isGuest is always true after login in Yii2

Tags: php, authentication, yii, yii2

I'm new to Yii and just started to creating signup and login modules.
Signing up is working, but when I try to login Yii::$app->user->isGuest is always true, but in LoginForm::login() it's working as it should and Yii::$app->user contains information of current user.
LoginForm.php:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 *
 * @property User|null $user This property is read-only.
 *
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $login;
    public $pass;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // login and password are both required
            [['login', 'pass'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['pass', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->pass)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Wrong login or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided login and password.
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate())
        {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user->active)
            {
                $this->addError('login', 'You account is not active.');
                return false;
            }
            return Yii::$app->user->login($user, $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[login]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false)
        {
            $this->_user = User::findByLogin($this->login);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php


namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * User model
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $login
 * @property string $pass
 * @property string $password_reset_token
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $auth_key
 * @property integer $status
 * @property integer $created_at
 * @property string $password write-only password
 */
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    /*public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }*/

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by login
     *
     * @param string $login
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findBylogin($login)
    {
        return static::findOne(['login' => $login]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->pass);
    }

    /**
     * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->pass = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }

    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }



    public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
    {

        if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
            return null;
        }

        return static::findOne([
            'password_reset_token' => $token,
            'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ]);
    }

    public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
    {
        if (empty($token)) {
            return false;
        }

        $timestamp = (int) substr($token, strrpos($token, '_') + 1);
        $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
        return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
    }

    public function generatePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }

    public function removePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = null;
    }
}
```

web.php containing these settings:

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
```

Session is have no data too. But server sessions are working fine.
View template have Yii::$app->user->isGuest always true.
Does anybody knows what is wrong?``

main.php:

```
<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use app\assets\AppAsset;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use app\models\LoginForm;

AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>

<div class="wrap">
    <?php
    NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => 'Cupimet',
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
        ],
    ]);
    /*echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
            ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
            ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
            Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? (
                ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']]
            ) : (
                '<li>'
                . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'], 'post')
                . Html::submitButton(
                    'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                    ['class' => 'btn btn-link logout']
                )
                . Html::endForm()
                . '</li>'
            )
        ],
    ]);*/
?>
    <div class="navbar-nav navbar-right login-form-head">
    <?php
    if (\Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
    {
        $model = new LoginForm;
        $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'action' => '/site/login',
            'id' => 'login-form',
            'layout' => 'inline',
            'fieldConfig' => [
                'template' => "{label}\n<div class=\"col-lg-3\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
                'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1 control-label'],
            ],
        ]);
    ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'login', ['template'=>'{input}<a href="/site/signup" class="regforgetlinx">Регистрация</a>'])->textInput(['placeHolder'=>'Логин']) ?>


        <?= $form->field($model, 'pass', ['template'=>'{input}<a href="/site/forgotpass" class="regforgetlinx">Забыли пароль?</a>'])->passwordInput(['placeHolder'=>'Пароль']) ?>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
                <?= Html::submitButton('ВОЙТИ', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-loginhead', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php
        ActiveForm::end();
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
        <div>Здравствуйте, <?=Yii::$app->user->login?></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
                <?= Html::submitButton('ВОЙТИ', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-loginhead', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
   </div>
    <?php

    NavBar::end();
    ?>

<div class="container">
        <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
            'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
        ]) ?>
        <?= $content ?>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text-center">&copy; cupimet Copyright <?= date('Y') ?></p>

    </div>
</footer>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

SiteController.php

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;
use app\models\SignupForm;
use app\models\User;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    /**
     * Login action.
     *
     * @return Response|string
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        }
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Logout action.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }

    /**
     * Displays contact page.
     *
     * @return Response|string
     */
    /*public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');

            return $this->refresh();
        }
        return $this->render('contact', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }*/

    /**
     * Displays about page.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    /*{
        return $this->render('about');
    }

    public function actionAddAdmin()
    {
    $model = User::find()->where(['login' => 'admin'])->one();
    if (empty($model)) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->login = 'admin';
        $user->email = 'admin@cupimet.ru';
        $user->setPassword('7777777');
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        if ($user->save()) {
            echo 'good';
        }
        print 777;
    }
    }*/

    public function actionSignup()
    {
        $model = new SignupForm();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($user = $model->signup()) {
                if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                    return $this->goHome();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('signup', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /*
     * Подтверждение подписки.
     * В качестве GET-параметра принимается код, который сравнивается с тем, что в таблице subscription
     * в ячейке activation. При успехе - ставится true в ячейку status.
     */
    public function actionActivation(){
        $code = Yii::$app->request->get('code');
        $code = Html::encode($code);
        //ищем код подтверждения в БД
        $find = User::find()->where(['email_confirm_token' => $code])->one();
        if($find){
            $find->active = 1;
            if ($find->save()) {
                $text = '<p>Поздравляем!</p>
                <p>Ваш e-mail подтвержден и регистрация завершена.</p>';
                //страница подтверждения
                return $this->render('activation', [
                    'text' => $text
                ]);
            }
        }

        $absoluteHomeUrl = Url::home(true);
        return $this->redirect($absoluteHomeUrl, 303); //на главную
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem solved. That was because status field was 0 instead of 10 in user table.

Comment: @Peter, you should update your question with information about how you solved it... or post an answer to your own problem. That way others might find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

If someone interested I've created different structure of MySQL user table and field "status" was set to 0. So I changed it to 10 and the problem was solved...

Comment: Hi Peter, i'm having this issue as well.  Can you please share more detail?  I don't see documentation on a user table design requirement

Comment: Dont really remember how I've fixed that, but I remember that I've installed new version of Yii and used standart login, instead of using my own authorization.

Comment: okay.  thanks.  I have a recent version, and I can tell that isGuest is being set to false on post because it's redirecting to the home page.  There's no session keeping the status though.  It's gone on load of the home view, and I can't see that the user is logged in.  I don't know if it's a database field or session config that I need.

Comment: I had a recent version of Yii2 too, but I started creating my own login and signup modules. And I got that error, dont remember why. And when I've installed Yii2 again and standart login module that error gone